# Why does introducing std::variant produce additional code unrelated to variant?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, variant

Consider a toy model of parsing a wire message format that looks something like this:

```
const int TYPE_A = 0xA;
const int TYPE_B = 0xB;

struct H { int type; };

struct A : public H
{
    int x = 0;
    char y = '?';
};

struct B : public H
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
};
```

The old fashioned way of doing this would be to use an H* pointer.  For instance we might write something like this:

```
int oldGetX(void * data)
{
  auto header = reinterpret_cast<H *>(data);

  switch(header->type)
  {
    case TYPE_A: return reinterpret_cast<A *>(data)->x;
    case TYPE_B: return reinterpret_cast<B *>(data)->x;
    default:     throw std::runtime_error("bad type");
  }
}
```

It seems like a more "modern" way to do this should be to use `std::variant`.  First, we'd write something like

```
std::variant<A, B> parse(void * data)
{
  auto header = reinterpret_cast<H *>(data);

  switch(header->type)
  {
    case TYPE_A: return *reinterpret_cast<A *>(data);
    case TYPE_B: return *reinterpret_cast<B *>(data);
    default:     throw std::runtime_error("bad type");
  }
}
```

and then we could write the equivalent of oldGetX() above like so:

```
int newGetX(void * data)
{
    const auto v = parse(data);

    if(std::holds_alternative<A>(v)) { return std::get<A>(v).x; }
    else                             { return std::get<B>(v).x; }
}
```

or, if we wanted to *really* do things the right way,

```
int newerGetX(void * data)
{
  return std::visit(
    [](const auto & t) -> int { return t.x; },
    parse(data));
}
```

However, the compiler seems to generate very different code for these three functions.  Now, I would understand if the difference seemed to be something related to the `std::variant` that it just wasn't quite able to figure out how to optimize out, but this doesn't seem to be the case at all.  Minus the exception handling, g++ 11.3.0 gives me the following at `-O3`:

```
0000000000000140 <oldGetX(void*)>:
 140:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
 144:   8b 07                   mov    (%rdi),%eax
 146:   83 f8 0a                cmp    $0xa,%eax
 149:   75 05                   jne    150 <oldGetX(void*)+0x10>
 14b:   8b 47 04                mov    0x4(%rdi),%eax
 14e:   c3                      ret    
 14f:   90                      nop
 150:   83 f8 0b                cmp    $0xb,%eax
 153:   75 06                   jne    15b <oldGetX(void*)+0x1b>
 155:   f2 0f 2c 47 08          cvttsd2si 0x8(%rdi),%eax
 15a:   c3                      ret
```

This is pretty straightforward: we check the `type` of the message; if it's type "A" we return `x`, and if it's type "B" we convert `x` from `double` to `int` and then return it.  Otherwise we jump to exception handling code (not shown).

Here's what it does for newGetX:

```
0000000000000070 <newGetX(void*)>:
  70:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  74:   8b 07                   mov    (%rdi),%eax
  76:   83 f8 0a                cmp    $0xa,%eax
  79:   75 0d                   jne    88 <newGetX(void*)+0x18>
  7b:   48 8b 07                mov    (%rdi),%rax
  7e:   48 c1 e8 20             shr    $0x20,%rax
  82:   c3                      ret    
  83:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  88:   41 54                   push   %r12
  8a:   55                      push   %rbp
  8b:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
  8f:   83 f8 0b                cmp    $0xb,%eax
  92:   75 16                   jne    aa <newGetX(void*)+0x3a>
  94:   f3 0f 6f 07             movdqu (%rdi),%xmm0
  98:   0f 29 04 24             movaps %xmm0,(%rsp)
  9c:   f2 0f 2c 44 24 08       cvttsd2si 0x8(%rsp),%eax
  a2:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
  a6:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  a7:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
  a9:   c3                      ret
```

For the type A case, instead of grabbing the value of x and throwing it into a 32-bit register, we grab x together with 32 extraneous bits, put them into a 64-bit extension of the same register, and then shift to get the value of x where we want it.  For the type B case the difference is similar.

For the case of newerGetX(), I get a *lot* more assembly, including stuff referencing `std::variant`, so apparently the compiler is just having trouble optimizing that version.

Questions:

1. Why does introducing `std::variant` make the optimizer generate different code, even though it's apparently optimized out everything actually related to `std::variant`?
2. Regarding the difference between `oldGetX` and `newGetX`, is this likely to have performance impact, or is it likely to be the same after taking into account pipelining, different timing for different instructions, etc.?  (I could benchmark it to get an answer for this, but I was wondering if there's a reason why we can see *in principle* that it necessarily will or won't be slower.)
3. Why does the compiler have trouble optimizing `newerGetX` versus `newGetX`?
4. Is there a better way to write this sort of code?  I would like to write code that looks more like newerGetX if possible for the sake of type safety and so that we don't have to duplicate the switch on `type` in every single method, but if there's a performance cost to this it seems like I may not want to do that.

Comment: How do you know everything about `std::variant` is optimized out?

Comment: variant is essentially a type safe union.  You don't get that safety for free

Comment: While for GCC 11.3, there is some Vtable overhead, for GCC 12.2, there is no real [difference](https://godbolt.org/z/qzEMWK3G6) any more.

Comment: @PasserBy: Because I'm looking at the assembly code it generated.

Comment: @NathanOliver: While that could be true in some situations, it's clear in this case from the generated assembly that the runtime cost I'm paying here has nothing to do with type safety.

Answer (score 1):

You're not making an apples-to-apples comparison here because your `newGetX` function, which has `parse` inlined into it, is copying the entire `A` or `B` object, as the case may be, into a `std::variant` object, just so it can later throw away the `y` member in each case that it doesn't care about.

In a realistic application, either

1. `parse` would be called once on the data when it comes over the wire, and the `variant<A, B>` object would be used in its place for the remainder of the processing. `newGetX` would take this variant object by reference. Or
2. The raw data would be kept somewhere and a `variant<A*, B*>` object (or perhaps `variant<const A*, const B*>`) would be used to provide type-safe access to its contents during its lifetime.

I understand that this is just a toy example. With that being said, if we go and make the `parse` function return `std::variant<A*, B*>` to avoid unnecessary copying:

```
std::variant<A*, B*> parse(void * data)
{
  auto header = reinterpret_cast<H *>(data);

  switch(header->type)
  {
    case TYPE_A: return reinterpret_cast<A *>(data);
    case TYPE_B: return reinterpret_cast<B *>(data);
    default:     throw std::runtime_error("bad type");
  }
}

int newGetX(void* data) {
    auto variant = parse(data);
    if (std::holds_alternative<A*>(variant)) {
        return std::get<A*>(variant)->x;
    } else {
        // no need to check again; exception will be propagated above
        return std::get<B*>(variant)->x;
    }
}
```

[With GCC 11.3.0](https://godbolt.org/z/MMb5d4ebs) I get the following:

```
oldGetX(void*):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     eax, 10
        jne     .L19
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
        ret
.L19:
        cmp     eax, 11
        jne     .L20
        cvttsd2si       eax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        ret
.L20:                   ; throw exception
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        push    rax
        jmp     .L15
```

and

```
newGetX(void*):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        cmp     eax, 10
        jne     .L41
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
        ret
.L41:
        cmp     eax, 11
        jne     .L35    ; throw exception
        cvttsd2si       eax, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        ret
```

So, in fact, the generated assembly for the two functions is identical on the happy path.

Comment: I see, this resolves the mystery re: point (1).  I told it to copy the whole object and so it's gonna copy the whole object, hence selecting a register big enough to do it.  Looks like this behavior persists if I make the structs a lot larger, meaning that using a `std::variant<A, B>` won't be performant.